# Records of densest sphere packings

Tags: packing-problem

Last year it was a big news that Maryna Viazovska solved the densest sphere packing problem in dimension 8. As you know, the proof for dimension 24 soon followed.

I would like to find the current records of densest sphere packings. I thought that someone managed the records. But I could hardly find such a site except for several fragmentary documents.

Is there anyone who have been managing the records? Is there such a diagram or a table showing the current records like the following diagram in Conway & Sloane's book?
[image]

Comment: What are the criterions for packing? How to measure density?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nebe and Sloane keep a [list of records](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/%7EGabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/density.html) as part of their catalog of lattices. Among all sources I’m aware of, it’s the most up to date and likely to be maintained.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you look for

http://neilsloane.com/doc/BEST/Me194.pdf